# Ubuntu update litecoin-qt wallet software

Tags: litecoin

I get this message when i run my litecoin-qt client:

```
all users must upgrade to litecoin 0.6.9.1 prior to 15 august 2013
```

so i downloaded the `litecoin-0.6.9.2-linux.tar.xz` file from litecoin.org and ran through this process: https://forum.litecoin.net/index.php?topic=43.0

Now i have the new litecoin daemon running but the qt client has not upgraded. How do I upgrade the client? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the instructions:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=63706.0

basically just need to run

```
qmake "USE_UPNP=-"
make
```

in the main directory to create the `litecoin-qt` file